# Ubuntu 22.04 is not displaying the audio input/output popup correctly

Tags: sound, 22.04

This started when I upgraded to 22.04. Everything was fine except for the popup for audio input/output screen. I have a screenshot of it showing the audio output volume change.

[image: The screenshot of the issue]

Although it all works the same and just fine, it still makes me confused why it broke. When there is like text to show like when turning on and off the microphone.

Note: (The screenshots) Yes, I themed my Ubuntu install with Mac themes. Also I would love to somehow modify the popup if possible. Maybe make it look like in the older versions.

Here is an example of it actually showing correctly when I use the microphone:

[image: The normal way it shows]